# Why is this jquery transfer not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm  a little confused why this effect transfer is not working in jquery.

my jquery files

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My HTML.

```
<img id="sample" class='trial' src='{{ url('taskAssets/'.$stimuli['sample'][0]) }}.jpg'/>
<a id="hello" href='response/{{ $stimuli['comparison'][5]}}'><img class='trial'  src='{{ url('taskAssets/'.$stimuli['comparison'][5]) }}.jpg' /></a></td>
```

My CSS for the transfer:

```
.ui-effects-transfer {
border: 5px solid black;
  }
```

And my jquery script

```
<script>


$("#sample").effect("transfer", {to: $("#hello")}, 1000);

</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the code before the DOM is finished loading. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sample").effect("transfer", { to: $("#hello") }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This is correct if the script as at the beginning of the HTML, not true if it's at the end.

Comment: So my script is at the at the end of the body. above the footer. But all the elements are before the the script. Also this document ready is not helping. Even my other effects $("#sample").effect("shake", { times: 50 }, 5000);
which work without the document ready stopped working. 

I also tried adding $("#sample").hide(); and it didn't work when wrapped with the .ready function

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle where it's working. Maybe you'll find a difference between my code and yours. https://jsfiddle.net/Ravvy/1tss5wqh/

Comment: So it's just in chrome it doesn't work actually. Works in firefox. Nothing works as soon as I put in the $(document).ready though which is alarming.